Proof about generalized property about regular tetrahedrons
I read a mathematical text called Theorem of Three Perpendiculars and used it to solve problems involving regular tetrahedrons

Qeustion:  Let $O_{base}$ be the center of gravity of triangle $ABC$, and find the angle formed by line $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$.

Answer: Since the orthogonal projection of line $\overline{AD}$, line $\overline{AO_{base}}$, is perpendicular to line $\overline{BC}$, the angle formed by lines $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ is perpendicular.

When I looked into this further, I found that this answer could be generalized to say, 'If a line segment is perpendicular to a projection, then the original line is also perpendicular.'
However, I feel that this is not enough, so I tried to do a more rigorous proof, but I had difficulty doing the proof myself, so I couldn't make much progress. So I'm asking a question here to get hints and directions.
Note: The source of the photo above is here.
Edit: I read the comment and got hint and thought of a proof based on the hint. Could you please confirm if this thought process is correct?

The proof is developed based on the picture above.
Start proof: Let us assume that there is a straight line $l$ passing through point $A$. In addition, the center of mass $O_{base}$ of the base $ABC$ is, by the definition of the center of mass of a triangle, the intersection of the line from point $A$ to the midpoint of line $\overline{BC}$, the line from point $B$ to the midpoint of line $\overline{AC}$, and the line from point $C$ to the midpoint of line $\overline{AB}$. Therefore, automatically, the line from point $A$ through point $O_{base}$ and the midpoint of line $\overline{BC}$ are perpendicular to $\overline{BC}$. In addition, by the Theorem of Three Perpendiculars, the straight line $\overline{DO_{base}}$ and triangle $ABC$ are perpendicular to each other, and the straight line $l$ passing through the point $A$ and $\overline{AD}$ are perpendicular to each other. Therefore, the straight line $\overline{AO_{base}}$ and the straight line $l$ are perpendicular to each other, and then, the straight line $l$ and the straight line $\overline{BC}$ are parallel to each other. Therefore, if the straight line $l$ is perpendicular to the orthographic projection $\overline{AO_{base}}$ of the straight line $\overline{AD}$, it is also perpendicular to the original straight line $\overline{AD}$.


HINT: construct through $A$ a line parallel to $BC$ and use the Theorem of Three Perpendiculars.

@Intelligentipauca Thanks I'll try it!!

@Intelligentipauca Hello, this is the proof I edited after reading your hint and thinking about it. Is this the flow of proof you intended when you gave the hint?

Your proof isn't correct: the line constructed through $A$ cannot be generic. I suggested to construct a line parallel to $BC$, because the "angle" of two skew lines (an ugly entity I would avoid) is by definition the angle formed by one of the lines and an incident parallel of the other line. Hence you must find the angle formed by the constructed line with $AD$.

@Intelligentipauca Thanks for your comment. Then, I'll use the Theorem of Three Perpendiculars to find the angle between $\overline{AD}$ and $l$. And then, I'll prove the line $l$ parallel to $\overline{BC}$. And if the latter part of my proof is wrong, could you please briefly explain the ideas of the proof in order?

Proof. Construct a line $l$ through $A$, parallel to $BC$. Line $AO_{base}$ is perpendicular to $BC$, as you proved. Hence $AO_{base}$ is perpendicular to $l$. But $DO_{base}$ is perpendicular to plane $ABC$:  from the Theorem of Three Perpendiculars it follows that $l$ is perpendicular to $AD$, QED.

@Intelligentipauca Thank you for your comment about proof! I understand your proof!!
